# Расчет хеша в Perl

Tags: perl

```
perl -e '%h= qw/q q w w e e r r t t/; $r = %h; print $r'
4/8

perl -e '%h= qw/q q/; $r = %h; print $r'
1/8
```

Вообщем-то сами разработчики перл не рекомендуют использовать расчет элементов подобным образом. И тем не менее охота разобраться... Вообщем-то я понимаю? что при расчете первого примера два элемента выдают одинаковый хеш-адрес и два значения помещаются в одну "строку". В связи с этим вместо  5/8 выдает 4/8.

Вопрос: кто-нибудь может показать или расписать формулу расчета?

Answer (score 1):

Что значит «формула расчета»?

Если вас интересует, какая именно хэш-функция используется в перле для обработки ключей хэша, то, вообще говоря, языком это никак не определяется, делать какие-то выводы из количества занятых/размещенных buckets не стоит.

Сейчас, afaik, в современных сборках перла обычно используется один из вариантов [функции Дженкинса](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jenkins_hash_function). Вы можете вызвать ее сами, она называется B::hash.

```
% perl -e 'use B; print B::hash($_), "\n" for (qw(q w e r t))'
0xefdd5f9b
0x58a0b120
0x11162210
0x26014be2
0x497812cf
```

Как видите, значения разные, и как именно распределятся 32-битные хэш-суммы по отведенным блокам памяти, увидеть отсюда нельзя.

Я попробовал в лоб пару идей, например, выделив младшие биты из хэш-суммы:

```
% perl -e 'use B; print hex(B::hash($_)) & 7, "," for (qw(q w e r t u x c v z))'
3,0,0,2,7,1,5,1,5,6,
```

но нифига не получается. На хэш из этих значений тоже отводится 4 из 8 блоков:

```
% perl -e '%h = (qw(q w e r t u x c v z)); print scalar %h'
4/8
```

Дальше угадывать ломает, лучше я загляну в исходники перла %)

Comment: Как то был на собеседовании и меня интервьюировал "мегамозг"
Записывать не было возможности - но уловил, что берутся ord ключей и как-то дальше они складываются хитро(или делятся)... Вообще "в инете найду" подумал я. Но не нашел - а интерес остался.
    лучше я загляну в исходники перла
Именно это мне и нужно =)

Comment: Еще: В вопросе я упомянул "хэш-адрес" - я не имел ввиду адрес-физический. Просто образно выразился. Просто ключ "w" и "e". При расчете ключа выдают одинаковый результат. И если расчет одинаковый, выполняется второй поиск(именно физического адреса) - возможно тупым перебором.
Внутри это выглядит примерно так:
    q
    w, e
    r
    t